Media Playback Controls Not Showing in Notification Area for Chrome on Ubuntu 24.04
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04, and I'm facing an issue where media playback controls do not appear in the notification area when streaming video in Chrome. I tried and experienced the same in Edge, or Epiphany browsers as well. Only VLC shows proper media playback controls in the notification area.
Notifications from these browsers work fine (show with icon). I’ve tried enabling experimental media flags and disabling hardware acceleration, but nothing has worked. Any suggestions?
